# How to add a DB into netbeans

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I have a website with a CPanel server, made in PHP, with MySQL DB. I only am familiar with Java so I am trying to get that DB into netbeans. Could someone please guide me on how to get it into NetBeans so that I can try to "operate" on it? The "create database" and "start server" buttons are not clickable when I right click on java DB. I already have the derby Jar in the classpath and in the library of the project.

[image: files + netbeans]

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/) and MySql are two different datbase systems. So if you want to work with your MySql database you don't need any Derby jars in your classpath.

You'll find a tutorial how to work with MySql in NetBeans here: https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html

If you still considering Derby you find a tutorial here: https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html

In a gist:

> - Right-click the Databases node in the Services window and choose Register MySQL Server to open the MySQL Server Properties dialog box.
> - Fill out the dialog.
> - To connect to the database server, confirm that the MySQL Database Server is running on your machine, right-click the Databases > MySQL
>   Server node in the Services window and choose Connect.

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I am a little confused. If I connect to a MySQL DB as shown in your resource, Can I then use the packages and classes of Derby, JPA or hibernate to alter the DB? Or is there another MySQL group of classes I would have to use?

Comment: The tutorial shows you how to connect to a MySql database from within NetBeans and use NetBeans as an editor. Only thing you'll need is a database driver.
You would use JPA/Hibernate if you want to operate on a database from within your Java program. 
I'm currently not sure if you want to use the IDE as an editor or want to write a program to access the database.

Comment: I did not know I could use the IDE as an editor. I will probably need to write a program. Because I have a CSV file with around 28 columns/fields. I need to try to take every row with a certain value in a certain column and have those email addresses/columns deleted from my active MySQL DB.